# How to pass attribute "association-insertion-node" as a function correctly?

Tags: coffeescript, cocoon-gem

What is link in example in cocoon documentation [Control the Insertion Behaviour](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#control-the-insertion-behaviour)
I receive an error "... is undefined" and if I pass a DOM object I get 'data-association-insertion-node="[object, Object]"'
    code:

```
$(".add-comment").on 'cocoon:before-insert', (e, object) ->
  wlink = $(this).children('a')
  wlink
    .attr(
      "data-association-insertion-node",
      (link) ->
        link.parents('.object-name').children('.comments')
    )
```

#### Update

Actually, it don't, it have only one nesting, and speaking about multiple nesting I have one in another part and it works fine, but there I use ids which generated in js before inserting so I have an ability to set association-insertion-node as a string.
But in this case, I haven't such opportunity, so that is why I've chosen traversal approach.

So what I'm saying is I didn't catch how it works

```
function(link){
    return link.closest('.row').next('.row').find('.sub_tasks_form')
}
```

because I get

```
TypeError: link.parents is not a function.
 (In 'link.parents('.object-name')', 'link.parents' is undefined)`
```

seemed like it must be declared and it isn't, maybe there is another point of entry of link, maybe it doesn't work because of coffee.

and if I pass `$(this)` I get

```
<a data-association-insertion-method="append" 
class="add_fields" data-association="comment" 
data-associations="comments" 
data-association-insertion-template="Generated HTML" 
href="#" data-association-insertion-node="[object Object]"> add comment</a>
```

And what I want is to traverse by DOM to post comments to relative objects.

#### p.s.

Thanks a lot for your attention.

Comment: Just to be clear: can you explain a little more what you are trying to do? It seems like upon insertion of a nested form, it contains another `link_to_add_association` (a double nested form) and want to control the insertion behaviour on that nested-nested form, is that correct? At first glance this seems to be correct imho (in the [documentation](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#control-the-insertion-behaviour) I use `data` instead of `attr` but imho that is identical).

Comment: I updated question

Answer (score 0):

> I use data instead of attr but imho that is identical). – nathanvda Mar 30 at 8:38

It matters. start work after change from attr to data.